# Best way to specify the local endpoint for HTTP request?

Tags: .net, sockets, http

I am trying to specify the local endpoint for some HTTP requests that I need to make.

Here is a simplified version of what I am doing now:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
  using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I am not tied to `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, and I am totally open to using other classes, like `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, to get the job done.

It would appear at least theoretically possible since Windows and `System.Net.Sockets` allows this with the `Bind` method. [Source IP address selection on a Multi-Homed Windows Computer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/24/source-ip-address-selection-on-a-multi-homed-windows-computer.aspx), [MSDN - Socket Class (System.Net.Sockets)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx)

Obviously this isn't possible, but in an ideal world, I could somehow access the underlying Socket like this:

```
client.Socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(167772161, 80));
```

Is there any way to do this without writing an entire HTTP client?

---

Here is a little more background on why I'm trying to do this, in case someone has a different solution all together. We have a webfarm with several machines each using a single NIC with several IP addresses (all on the same gateway). We'd like to have each application using it's own IP address for external requests.

Here is a simplified version:

1. Machine 1

   1. App 1 (10.0.1.10 / 255.255.0.0)
   2. App 2 (10.0.1.11 / 255.255.0.0)
   3. etc..
2. Machine 2

   1. App 1 (10.0.2.10 / 255.255.0.0)
   2. App 2 (10.0.2.11 / 255.255.0.0)
   3. etc...
3. etc...

Traffic is routed from 172.16.0.2 (app 1 external) to 10.0.x.10 (app 1 internal), from 172.16.0.3 (app 2 external) to 10.0.x.11 (app 2 internal), etc. We are trying to avoid external requests from app 2 using 172.16.0.2 (app 1 external), because it's using 10.0.x.10 as a local address instead of 10.0.x.11.

Quick network diagram of the simplified example, in case that helps at all:
[image: example network diagram]

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. You're making a HTTP request to some URL - that URL already has the IP address in it. I don't quite see where the servers and clients are supposed to be. Also, how can you have a single NIC with many different IP addresses?

Comment: That is the destination IP address. I am trying to change the source IP address. You can add more IP addresses in the advanced TCP/IP settings of your NIC.

Comment: I am 100% sure I have multiple IP addresses. Here is a question that explains how you can do it if you're interested: http://serverfault.com/questions/868/multiple-ip-addresses-per-nic

Comment: Oh, interesting. What are you trying to achieve with this (what is your underlying problem)? Distinguishing your applications on the remote server? Different configurations for the firewall?

Comment: The goal is distinguishing on the remote server. Some of the applications we run make external HTTP requests. Lets say Bob the client signs up for App 2, which in this example runs on a machine with App 1 as well. He wants us to notify him via HTTP request when some important change occurs. When that change happens, App 2 makes a request to Bob's callback at http://bobsite.com/callback/app2. Ideally that request would always come from the IP that Bob knows is associated with App 2. However, without specifying, it is left up to .Net or Windows to decide, and it might end up looking like App 1.

Comment: Wouldn't the request get the IP of the router anyway, rather than the actual server application? Wouldn't it be a better idea to identify the application through a HTTP header? Or through the request URL? That's the proper HTTP protocol anyway. You shouldn't rely on infrastructure details, because they often aren't propagated (e.g. routers, firewalls, proxies...).

Comment: Our router is assigned public IP addresses, our firewall maps each public IP to an internal IP from 172.16.0.1/16, and our load balancer then maps each 172.16.0.x address to set of 10.0.x.y addresses. If an app uses a given 10.0.x.y address that will route to the corresponding 172.16.0.x address, and again to a unique external address.

It may not be ideal, but it is a feature fully supported by Winsock (http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;175396) and at least theoretically by the .Net framework as well. And, we're hoping to avoid costly network infrastructure changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpClient` doesn't allow you to do this. However, `HttpWebRequest` does!

A `HttpWebRequest` can be associated with a `ServicePoint` object, which manages the HTTP connections. This allows you to pass an `IPEndPoint` you own. A simple example:

```
var req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.com/");

req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = 
  (s, ep, retries) => 
    new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.1.10"), 1234 + retries);

var response = req.GetResponse();
```

Note that the port is *not* `80` - the reason I've added the `retries` to the port number is because each client socket needs to have a unique port number.

You'd probably do well to research the proper usage of this better, I'm pretty sure this is a lot dirtier than the designers of that interface intended. But it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate looks like exactly what I need to get this working.

Comment: you can use port no `0` , that will auto select a free local port.

Comment: This feature is not yet Implemented in .Net Core, so this only works in .net framework. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28721

Comment: @lmsm3 Yeah, .NET Core didn't exist back in 2014 :)